# C++ O(1) [x in s] where x is an value and s is a data structure

Tags: python, c++, data-structures

I am learning C++ with a python background, and want to know if there is a data structure similar to the python "set". For the set in python, there is O(1) for x in s. What data structure in C++ has similar / same properties as the python set?

[Python Set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `std::unordered_set` to achieve similar [runtime complexity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

> Unordered set is an associative container that contains a set of
>   unique objects of type Key. Search, insertion, and removal have
>   average constant-time complexity.

You can use the [find method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) to lookup a specific item.

Or even the [count method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/count) if all you want is to determine if a specific item is on the list (return 1 or 0)

Have in mind that Python's `set` uses a hash table to make the lookup in constant time, the same for `dict`.
In modern C++ a `std::map` is a binary tree, a `std::unordered_map` is a hash table, the same applies for `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`.

Answer (score 0):

`set` in Python uses a hash table, the comparable in C++ is `[std::unordered_set][1]`